# How to change logo on site when reaching specific row

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress

Using Wordpress (Theme Definity 2) I want to change the Logo in the header when scrollingly reaching a certain row (id= designingfuture). 
I tried everything I can with CSS, but couldn't figure out how to.

Do I need Javascript?
What could possibly work with Javascript?

That's the site I'm talking about:
www.u-m-j.de

Hope you can help and sorry that I couldn't provise code I tried, for there is none I was capable to try.

Answer (score 0):

Ofcourse u need javascript.
because you can't detect the current position of window or scrolling through css. 
you can use the following code to achieve this

```
<img id="HdrLogo" src="default-logo.png">

$(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if (($('#designingfuture').offset().top - $(window).scrollTop()) <= 100){
            $("#HdrLogo").attr("src","onscroll-logo.png");
        }
        else{
            $("#HdrLogo").attr("src","default-logo.png");
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: In thie above snippet, I used jquery library. make sure jquery is included

Comment: after making sure jquery is present, 
if u face $ uncaught reference error due to wp environment, then replace '$' with 'jQuery' everywhere and try again

Comment: Thanks a lot already!
As far as I see, that code replaces the image on scroll, doesn't it?
I actually meant, that the image should be replaced, when reaching a certain point at the site (the row with id=designingfuture").
Is that even possible?

Comment: $('#designingfuture').offset().top - $(window).scrollTop()

this above statement will return the distance between 'designingfuture' element and window top. using this you can replace theimage based on the position of the  'designingfuture' element

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment to the answer, you can use the calculation between the item and the offset to the top of the browser.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var elementTop = $('#designingfuture').offset().top;
    var elementBottom = elementTop + $('#designingfuture').outerHeight();
    var viewportTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var viewportBottom = viewportTop + $(window).height();

   if (elementBottom > viewportTop && elementTop < viewportBottom) {
       $("#HdrLogo").attr("src", "default-logo.png");
   }
});
```